# Regards TFS bindings VS2015

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, tfs

I am new to TFS. I have a project of C# win forms. We are maintaining the projects with versions like v2018,v2019...

I have added v2018 project in TFS. It is working fine.

Now I took the v2018 project from TFS and took it out and removed all '*.*scc' extension files and made some changes inside the project and made that project version as v2019. The project is working fine outside.

Now I want to add this v2019 project to TFS as v2019.
But I am unable to add the project to TFS. While I am clicking over the solution and add this to Source control but it is adding only solution file to the TFS.

Why i am unable to add the whole project to the TFS.

Don't know what is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Under Team Explorer -> Pending Changes -> Excluded Changes you should see something like this:

[image]

If you click on that `Detected X add(s)` you should see a list of all the files that have not been added to source control. Just tick them and then click "Promote"